# What is a suitable regression model to analyse the associations of binary covariates with age of onset in a case-only study?

Tags: regression

In my data, all observations reach the endpoint (here disease). I would like to investigate the dependence of the age of onset of disease on binary covariates (e.g. smoking yes/no etc.). What would be a suitable model here, or is there a standard regression procedure that is typically used to analyze such data?

Comment: "Dummy variable regression" may be worth a try. Afterwards, you may want to learn something about "interaction effects".

Comment: I had thought of Poisson regression. Would there be anything wrong with that?

Comment: With the information I have about your problem, I wouldn't go for Poisson regression, as I assume that your response variable, age of onset of disease, is not Poisson distributed.